# NativeScript - apk build fails due to unsupported platform for tns-ios?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I'm sort of new to NativeScript, so I apologize if this answer is obvious but I'm a little confused.  I started building an app for android on a windows PC.  I have no issues building an apk file or running it in an emulator.

I eventually shifted that same code over to a mac so I could update the ios side of the app, and to build an ipa and run it in an iPhone emulator.  That all works.

Now, I'm bringing that *same* code back over to PC with the updated IOS code, but when I run `tns build android` I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for tns-ios@2.0.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Why would NativeScript force me to do this on a mac if I'm deliberately (and only) trying to build an apk file in windows?  It seems like the fact that I shifted over to a mac now forces me to stay on a mac?

Is there a way I can get NativeScript to ignore the IOS stuff when compiling an apk - other than maintaining two codebases?  Something seems off to me.  I removed `platforms` `node_modules` and `hooks` directories and tried to rebuild but I keep getting the same error.  If I revert the code back to what it was before I moved it over to mac I can successfully compile the APK file in windows.

The only thing I've done between the two is add firebase cloud messaging - which actually existed in the android version before I moved to a mac, and some images.  I thought maybe firebase might be interfering but I set `using_ios` to `false` in `firebase.nativescript.json` but that did not do anything, either.

I also tried `tns platform remove ios` but apparently it isn't even added on the PC side, which makes sense because you have to have a mac to add it.  Hence, why I'm scratching my head over this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how/when/why tns-ios version is 2.0.0 in package.json but updating it to 6.5.2 resolved the issue.